# Djnago superuser login does not work with --noinput option

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Super user is being created successfully with `--noinput` option, but login does not work in admin site.

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=123#$asdWE
python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username admin --email ad@admin.com
```

login of a superuser without `--noinput` (manual password typing) is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look, the char `#` is truncating the password.

```
#BAD
dani@dani / % DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=123#$asdWE
dani@dani / % echo $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD 
123#
```

Solution: Use quotes, also, export the env var:

```
#OK
dani@dani / % export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD='123#$asdWE' #<- quotes & export
dani@dani / % echo $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD       
123#$asdWE
```

Comment: Still it does not work. I tried DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD='123@@asdWE'
echo $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username admin --email ad@admin.com . It says "user created" and the password is also correctly printed but when I try to login in admin, it does not work.

Comment: Did you try to export the variable? `export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD='123#$asdWE'` ?

Comment: that worked.. thanks. please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

just creating a superuser successfully doesn't mean you have a superuser with the ability of logging into the admin page.
first you should check if the password correctly set or not
maybe you are setting the environment variable in a wrong way and the password didn't set so you can test it by changing the password in shell and retry to login to admin page
don't forget to use set_password function to change password